# How do I untrigger scroll lock on the map view?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I just won a combat after-which it was impossible for me to scroll around the main map with my mouse. I was locked entirely to the area centered around my hero.

I checked under the hotkeys, but I didn't see any sort of "scroll lock" toggle. What do I need to do to be able to scroll the map again? (Or is this just a bug like the flickering cursor?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug. There is no "scroll lock" option, but this is sometimes triggered if you try to scroll the camera too soon after an auto-save.

The only way to resolve the issue is to quit the game and reload.

Answer (score 4):

Well I had the same problem, but I found you can click on mouse wheel button and then move it in the direction where you want to move the camera. Other than this you have to restart the game.